# providedIn: 'root' automatically declare services for testing

Tags: angular

Maybe it's side effect of this new functionality, but if I have a service as

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService {...}
```

and I have `MyComponent` which uses this. Now, when I make a test for that component, I simply do and it works!

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [ MyComponent ]
})
.compileComponents();
```

That means that my service **implicitly** provided. I think it's very dangerous behaviour for testing. Is it possible to prevent this auto-providing?

Answer (score 2):

Use Testbed.overrideProvider in your case it will be

```
TestBed.overrideProvider(MyService, { useValue: MyServiceMock });
```

Comment: it doesn't solve initial problem because you have to do it for every provider

Answer (score 0):

Use old syntax:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {...}
```

and inject the service in providers array of root module or respective module.

If you use this approach, You won't be able to use the new feature : tree-shakeable providers.

Comment: This is not an approach the user would like to take

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue and I did some research. Short answer from an article:

> All the services registered with `providedIn` aren’t loaded in the test, they are instantiated lazily, only when they are really needed.

Reference: https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2018/05/04/what-is-new-angular-6/

Comment: > they are instantiated lazily, only when they are really needed
in my understanding it happens when I create a component instance for example. This will create all dependent services implicitly